# Identity server 4 Client Model for .net

Tags: .net, identityserver4

There are two client models in Identity Server 4

1. `IdentityServer4.Models.Client` from Assembly `IdentityServer4.Storage`

another from

2. `IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Entities.Client` from Assembly `IdentityServer4.EntityFramework`

Why there are 2 different implementations, which one should be used to create a new Client.

**Edit**:
specific question I want to ask is related to AllowedScopes:

from (1) the `Client.AllowedScope` => `public ICollection<string> AllowedScopes { get; set; }`

but from (2) the  `Client.AllowedScope` => `public List<ClientScope> AllowedScopes { get; set; }`.

so which one to choose while creating Dtos, Mapping, DB modeling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyone who stumbles upon here,

If you are using EF with IDSv4, use EF classes to model db, use Dtos as per your need (consider Dtos as ViewModels, atleast I did in my case) and use Mappers to do the trick.

also this could be useful 
`IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Mappers` for `IdentityServer4.Models.Client` to `IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Entities.Client`

The problem I faced was due to some package version and update issue, which I resolved manually. Still if someone faces problem more than happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

`IdentityServer4.Models.Client` from Assembly `IdentityServer4.Storage` is the model for their `IClientStore` interface.

`IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Entities.Client` from Assembly `IdentityServer4.EntityFramework` is the model for the concrete implementation of the above mentioned interface (`IClientStore`) to store configuration data in the database (for any EF compatible provider). It uses both models in the concrete implementation and just has an `Automapper` mapping between the two.

So to answer your question you technically don't have to use any of the above, but if you are trying to create your own concrete implementation of `IClientStore` with your own database provider (or other kind of data provider) then you would need to use `IdentityServer4.Models.Client` and provide a mapping between that and your type.

Comment: So, Why I can't use both of them together.
because I have to refer both the namespaces in different tiers of app (DI services), and some other places, both ends up in API layer where I am getting exception of ambiguous reference.

Comment: @BhanuChhabra you can use both of them, but they are not interchangeable types and if you do end up using both of them, you will need to use a "more" qualified name to identify the type in the appropriate assembly. They have to do this even in the Identity Server src code themselves (https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Storage/blob/dev/src/Mappers/ClientMappers.cs). This is just something you have to deal with if you have to refer to two different types with the same name.

Comment: Yes, it is done, I was trying to do same but there were some dependent service which needed to be updated.

But Visual studio kept on failing updating nuget packages, restarting system and cleaning bin/obj folder, following manual editing in csproj file did the trick

Thanks anyway. :)